# Ejabberd tsung test limits to 1005 online users

Tags: ejabberd, tsung

I need test max online users supported by my ejabberd. I use tsung, but i faced issue, inly 1005 online users from 1 client computer.

I have run tsung -l tsung-logs -f chat-4k.xml start

chat-4k.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/usr/local/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="info" version="1.0" dumptraffic="false">

  <clients>
    <client host="localhost" maxusers="200000"/>
  </clients>

  <servers>
    <server host="jabberserver" port="5222" type="tcp"/>
  </servers>

  <load>
    <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="14400" unit="minute">
      <users arrivalrate="10" unit="second"></users>
    </arrivalphase>
  </load>

  <options>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="global_number" value="100"></option>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="userid_max" value="100000"></option>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="domain" value="tst.pinkmess.xyz"></option>
    <option name="file_server" id='userdb' value="/tmp/test/userlist4.csv"/>
    <!-- <option type="ts_jabber" name="username" value="user"></option>
    <option type="ts_jabber" name="passwd" value="pass"></option> -->
  </options>

  <sessions>
   <session bidi="true" probability="100" name="xmpp" type="ts_jabber">

          <setdynvars sourcetype="file" fileid="userdb" delimiter=";" order="iter">
            <var name="username" />
            <var name="password" />
          </setdynvars>

        <transaction name="initial_stream">
            <request subst="true">
              <jabber type="connect" ack="local">
                    <xmpp_authenticate username="%%_username%%" passwd="%%_password%%"/>
              </jabber>
            </request>
        </transaction>

      <thinktime value="2"/>

      <transaction name="authenticate">
          <request> <jabber type="auth_sasl" ack="local"/> </request>
          <request> <jabber type="connect" ack="local"/> </request>
          <request> <jabber type="auth_sasl_bind" ack="local"/> </request>
          <request> <jabber type="auth_sasl_session" ack="local"/> </request>
      </transaction>

      <thinktime value="1"/>

      <request subst="true">
        <jabber type="presence:initial" ack="no_ack"/>
      </request>

      <for from="1" to="100" incr="1" var="j">
        <request subst="true">
          <jabber type="chat" ack="no_ack" size="500" destination="online"/>
        </request>
        <thinktime value="5"/>
      </for>

      <request subst="true">
        <jabber type="presence:final" ack="no_ack"/>
      </request>

  </session>
 </sessions>
</tsung>
```

Only 1005 online users from one client computer. I have run test on another  client VM it also gives 1005 online users. From 2 client VM a generates only 2010 online users.

Tung log has error

```
stats: dump at 1571563726
stats: users 1006 1009
stats: {cpu,"tsung_controller@nb-ivanov"} 1 46.80573663624511 0.0 57.691309987029825 32.14969234558683 41.291614334365065 10
stats: {load,"tsung_controller@nb-ivanov"} 1 1.609375 0.0 2.01171875 1.609375 1.812890625 10
stats: {freemem,"tsung_controller@nb-ivanov"} 1 2144.73046875 0.0 2294.95703125 2135.203125 2183.86171875 10
stats: session 28 77.93410714285714 9.264334616224604 108.182 68.178 0 0
stats: users_count 91 1034
stats: finish_users_count 28 28
stats: request 445 47.600876404494386 21.31547418108496 140.158 0.03 48.23643842794759 4580
stats: connect 65 42.36301538461539 4.39096055547796 85.906 33.592 42.63856170212765 940
stats: page 2225 9.801699775280849 36.93811095526636 245.732 0.009 19.20556423001114 11669
stats: tr_authenticate 96 166.69216666666654 31.625195579983718 246.623 108.536 155.72595489548956 909
stats: request_noack 2064 11884
stats: tr_initial_stream 88 85.87685227272726 11.180942522617931 141.442 66.816 88.95005212765957 940
stats: size_rcv 1408228 8612676
stats: async_unknown_data_rcv 2135 12866
stats: error_connect_emfile 96 96
stats: size_sent 1206452 7012283
stats: connected 65 1005
stats: error_abort_max_conn_retries 23 23
```

How to increase connected online users form one client VM?

Answer (score 1):

See step 1 in this tutorial, maybe your clients are limited, and you need to set ulimit or other system setting? https://www.ejabberd.im/benchmark/index.html